# Listing Strings without arrays?

Tags: java

How do I go about getting the result of all the string inputs to print as a list with out the use of arrays? For example, I'd like the list to print vertically, like below, rather than all on one line:

```
kidsname

bookname


kidsname

bookname
```

I appreciate any help which can steer me in the right direction!

```
package part3;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class listnames {

    private static Scanner kb;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String finished;
        String kidsname;
        String storage = " ";
        String bookname;
        String storageb = " ";
        String storagec = " ";
        int noofchild;

        kb = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("How many Children do you have?");
        noofchild = kb.nextInt();

        for (int k = 1; k <= noofchild; k++) {
            System.out.print("What is the kids name?");
            kidsname = kb.next();
            storage += (String.valueOf(kidsname) + "\t");

            do {

                System.out.print("What book did they buy?");
                bookname = kb.next();
                storageb += (String.valueOf(bookname) + "\t");
                System.out.print("Do you want to finish? y/n ");
                finished = kb.next();
                storagec = (storage + ("\n-----------------------\n") + storageb);
            } while (finished.equalsIgnoreCase("n"));

            System.out.println();

            System.out.print(storagec);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear and you've got WAY too much whitespace for a SO post.  This much whitespace in your actual code is fine.  But for a post on here, way too much.

Comment: @nhgrif:  ...and just like that, IntelliJ solves the whitespace problem. ;)

Comment: Sorry I'm still getting used to the website, appreciate the help, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's almost like you're doing too much here.  You have `kidsname` and `bookname` already declared as variables, yet you're storing them with tabs appended to the end, which is overly verbose, and a bit confusing.

Furthermore, your `do...while` loop seems misplaced; you're always going to be overwriting the value of `bookname` if someone decides to continue (even by entering `"&"` they'll continue).

Lastly, since you know you're dealing with `String`s, `String#valueOf` is unnecessary.  In actuality, since you're going to be placing a new line after the tab character, the tab character is also unnecessary.

So, a few things:

- Remove `storagea`, `storageb`, and `storagec` - they serve no real purpose.
- Move your printing statement inside of the `do...while`.  This way, you can print one child name per with multiple book names per iteration.
- Change `System.out.print` to `System.out.println`.  **Everywhere.**

Your printing statement would ultimately read like this:

```
System.out.println(kidsname + "\n-----------------------\n" + bookname);
```

---

**EDIT**:  If you want `bookname` to hold more than one element, keep appending to it.  Initialize it to the empty string, then when you read the line, append to it and append a newline as well.

```
bookname = kb.next() + "\n";
```

Comment: I understand its confusing, but what I'm trying to do is prompt the user (i) How man children there are, (ii)to enter the child s name and (iii) enter the title of the book they want (it can be more than one hence the y/n loop) and then at the end to print each child's name, the list of books they want underneath. I'm sorry, I'm new to java and I realise it must be frustrating to decipher what someone's trying create from there code alone.

Comment: It's not that I can't read code, nor is it that it's frustrating.  Had you made the part about you wanting multiple book names a bit clearer, I'd have provided you with a more pointed answer.  Allow me to revise my answer.

Answer (score 1):

`storageb +=(String.valueOf(bookname)+"\t");` -->  `storageb +=(String.valueOf(bookname)+"\n");`

Answer (score 0):

You keep outputting the string using `System.out.print()`. Try using `System.out.println` instead.